# What happens if one casts Imperio on oneself?

Tags: harry-potter, spells, unforgivable-curse

What happened if one cast the Imperius Curse on oneself? Imperio gives you control of over someone, so would it have any effect?

Somehow related: [Can the Killing Curse be used to commit suicide?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/89759/can-the-killing-curse-be-used-to-commit-suicide)

Comment: The universe collapses in on itself.

Comment: Their head explodes.

Comment: See the Scars of Mirrodin set FAQ at https://archive.wizards.com/dci/downloads/EN_MTGSOM_FAQ_20100922.rtf .  The relevant ruling in it says "You could gain control of yourself with Mindslaver's ability, but unless you do so to overwrite someone else's player-controlling effect, this doesn't do anything."

Comment: Well, you would probably have control over yourself. I'm guessing it's pretty underwhelming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the least the caster would feel a...

> "...floating sensation as every thought and worry in his head was wiped gently away, leaving nothing but a vague, untraceable happiness" -the goblet of fire

the potential for a miscast or poorly performed imperious curse could send you to St. Mungos quacking like a duck, as was the case with Herbert Chorley.

Comment: I should add this is all assuming you can successfully cast a spell, by making the correct verbal and physical gestures with your own wand pointed at yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I would guess this is impossible.

- First of all, it is well established in cannon that casting an Unforgivable Curse requires a good amount of anger and hate towards the target. Thus when casting the Imperius Curse you would need to deeply hate yourself (which is already fairly rare) and want yourself to relinquish all control of yourself to yourself which is nonsensical.
- Another point that should be considered is that wands have a tendency to refuse to hurt/curse their rightful owner. So it is very likely that your wand would refuse to perform the curse.

Comment: I don't think it's true that you need to hate the target of the Imperius curse in order to use it successfully. There's no mention of Harry summoning up any venom when he uses it at Gringotts. You need a really powerful, presumably hateful bit of emotion behind Avada Kedavra, yes, and you need to want and enjoy causing pain to cast a strong Cruciatus curse, but there's nothing to suggest that's necessary for the Imperius curse. Also, you can summon up the emotion and channel it without necessarily hating the target. I doubt Bellatrix had particularly strong feelings towards the fox she killed.

Comment: @Au101 It could have been an Auror in disguise!

Comment: @Au101 maybe you just need to really want to control the person - Harry remembers Bellatrix say 'you need to mean them' in Gringotts about unforgivables