# Why would Lupin kill Pettigrew?

Tags: harry-potter, remus-lupin

In Chapter Nineteen of *Prisoner of Azkaban* after a lengthy discussion in the Shrieking Shack, Lupin and Sirius decide to kill Pettigrew:

> "You should have realized," said Lupin quietly, "if Voldemort didn't kill you, we would. Good-bye Peter."

In the end Harry prevents them from doing it, but why would they have done it in the first place? In order to clear Sirius they would have to present Pettigrew, either alive or dead, as mentioned in Chapter Twenty-One:

> "Sirius has not acted like an innocent man. The attack on the Fat Lady – entering Gryffindor Tower with a knife – without Pettigrew, alive or dead, we have no chance of overturning Sirius's sentence."

However, if they turn up with Pettigrew dead then they have to explain how he died. It would then be possible, even probable, that the Ministry would realize that they were the murderers. Murdering a fellow human being carries a life sentence in Azkaban, as per Chapter Fourteen of*Goblet of Fire*:

> "Now... those three curses –  *Avada Kedavra*, Imperius, and Cruciatus –  are known as the Unforgivable Curses. The use of any one of them on a fellow human being is enough to earn a life sentence in Azkaban.

Why would Lupin risk a life sentence in Azkaban just to kill Pettigrew? And from the context it does not appear that this was a rash decision in a fit of passion. He seems to have calmly decided that this is the best course of action, without any concern for the consequences.

Comment: It's all very well to second-guess them, but it's not like keeping him alive worked out all that well for them either!

Comment: Per your last quote, technically it is using *Avada Kedavra* to kill someone that carries a life sentence; I suppose it is possible that murder by more mundane means may carry a lesser sentence, particularly if there are mitigating circumstances.

Comment: 1. "... alive or dead, we have no chance of overturning Sirius's sentence" Presumably they had the idea that a dead Pettigrew will still be enough to overturn the sentence. 2. "...The use of any one of them on a fellow human being is enough to earn a life sentence in Azkaban." It's *avada kedavra* (or any one of the 3) that carries a life sentence, not necessarily just killing someone

Answer (score 63):

If they killed Peter Pettigrew, they could simply claim that he died in the course of his capture.  They don't need him to be alive to prove that Sirius was innocent; they just need his body.

Pettigrew was a Death Eater, who had successfully pinned one of his previous crimes on someone else, and who had managed to evade detection and capture for over a decade.  He's clearly a dangerous and ruthless individual who is capable of taking extreme acts to remain free (like pretending to be a pet rat for years at a time).  No one would blink an eye if you failed to bring him in alive.

Of course, telling that lie would require Lupin and Black to be less than perfectly honorable and scrupulous, but they weren't saints.

Comment: It's still illegal for them to have killed Pettigrew. They would still be arrested!

Comment: So...Harry was arrested when he killed Voldemort?  All three times?  And when he killed Professor Quirrell?  There seems to be pretty broad latitude for self-defense in the wizarding world.  And necessarily so - just about everyone is armed at all times.  And even people who aren't armed - including elementary school age children - are dangerous.

Comment: Harry never used _Avada Kedavra_... It was by (I feel uncomfortable saying this) chance that Harry killed those people. Voldemort only died because his own curse rebounded!

Comment: They don't need to use *Avada Kedavra* to kill him.  Lupin never even begins his spell before Harry springs to Pettigrew's defense, so we don't have a way of knowing what spell he was going to use.  Heck, *Levicorpus* can be fatal if you use it correctly. (Maybe not inside a cramped cabin room, but still.)  There must be dozens of spells that can be used to kill.

Comment: Point taken, and they must be illegal to be used in that fatal way.

Comment: @tbrookside: They teach the most dangerous of all magics to first year students. It's like they're just waiting for a muggleborn to unlock its power.

Comment: @INTERESTING I mean one of the early spells they learn (Wingardium Leviosa) is easy enough to kill with.  Levitate a person high enough (~100 feet) and drop them, they'll likely die.  Levitate an object and drop it on them (such as a troll's club or a piano), they'll also likely die.  There's so many options for them to kill Pettigrew with without resorting to the Unforgivables, and even without resorting to anything approaching a "dark" curse.

Comment: @Joshua Yeah, Rowling definitely didn't playtest her low-level spells for balance.  The mage class is definitely broken.

Comment: @fyrepenguin I think it's unlikely that Wizards would die from getting dropped, actually- we see a few Quidditch crashes, and they walk off from what should be lethal falls with just a broken bone or two.

Comment: @nick012000: That's a good point. And IIRC, Neville Longbottom's family thought he was a squib until a relative dropped him out a window, onto his head, and he bounced instead of dying.

Comment: @nick012000 Everyone freaked out when Harry was knocked off his broom, and the attempt to do so by Quirrel was explicitly an attempt to kill him, so there's some hight that's both lethal and attainable. A fall down the center of the main staircase from one of the upper floors would probably be fatal, or one could go the Tralawney route and simply use WL to drop heavy objects from a suitable height. And that's just WL, aguamenti and incendio both have horrifying potential for lethality.

Comment: @tbrookside Most spells have counter-spells or ways to defend against them. The only reason why _Avata Kedavra_ is so powerful is that it _can't_ be blocked and is invariably lethal.

Comment: @forest Except when it isn't

Comment: @INTERESTING when aurors, Order of the Phoenix members, or just any enemies of the dark wizards/Death Eaters are fighting the bad, they are surely not throwing cotton balls at them. There are many dangerous and even lethal spells and I think, I remember even an in-universe character (Hermione perhaps) pointing out that the classification of “unforgivable” for just these three spells is entirely arbitrary (and at least in the books, even Harry uses two of them).

Comment: Perhaps relevant (and funny) http://archives.sluggy.com/book.php?chapter=55#2008-03-28

Comment: @INTERESTING Voldemort was hit by Avada Kedavra two times, one time it was intentionally directed at him by Harry (just not cast).

Comment: @FabianRöling What do you mean, _"intentionally directed?"_ Can you give me the moment in the book?

Comment: @INTERESTING The finale.

Comment: @FabianRöling Where Voldemort finally topples? Nope. That was Voldemort's curse rebounding, and it wasn't directed by Harry.

Comment: There was a back and forth between the beams and they both tried to force it onto the other, that's what I mean.

Comment: @FabianRöling If I remember right, in the books there is no finale beam struggle, that was added for the movies. In the books Harry is definitely attempting to disarm, and Voldemorts curse rebounds. Even in the movies the beam struggle shouldn't have happened, since beam struggles are caused by two brother wands being forced to fight, but in DH Harry is using the Elder Wand.

Comment: @tbrookside that's why everyone sane one playing is a wizard and the others are only NPCs...

Comment: you don't need to cast avada kedavra to kill

Answer (score 21):

## He wanted revenge...

...for Jame's and Lily's deaths. After all, it was Pettigrew that caused them to die!

> “Harry, this piece of vermin is the reason you have no parents,” Black snarled. “This cringing bit of filth would have seen you die too, without turning a hair. You heard him. His own stinking skin meant more to him than your whole family.”

---

As for the Ministry realizing that they were murders, everybody thinks Pettigrew is dead, anyway! They would never realize that he had *actually* been murdered!

> “When I cornered him, he yelled for the whole street to hear that I’d betrayed Lily and James. Then, before I could curse him, he blew apart the street with the wand behind his back, killed everyone within twenty feet of himself — and sped down into the sewer with the other rats...”

After they've killed him, it's easy to lie about how he died. Perhaps the all-consuming guilt forced Peter to put a wand to his head and say *Avada Kedavra!* After being confronted by Lupin and Sirius, he began to finally feel remorse for his actions.

<sup>*(There are possibly better lies out there! I'm not great at lying, myself!)*</sup>

---

So, really, **they have nothing to lose** by killing him, **they would get their revenge**, and **nobody would find out**! *Brilliant!*

Comment: They need to produce the body in order to clear Sirius. Plus at that point Snape knew that Lupin was colluding with Sirius. And they would have to rely on Harry, Hermione, and Ron to keep quiet.

Comment: @Alex Simple memory charm should deal with Snape! Also, they could lie about how Peter died. Maybe the overwhelming guilt caused him to kill himself. Why would the three _not_ keep quiet?

Comment: I guess that's possible. Still seems risky though.

Comment: @Alex "The risk would’ve been what made it fun..."

Comment: "...without Pettigrew, alive or dead, we have no chance of overturning Sirius's sentence." This line makes it clear that it wasn't their goal to get rid of the body and pretend it didn't happen.

Comment: @Laurel I will edit my answer based on the comments between Alex and I...

Comment: "*Perhaps the all-consuming guilt forced Peter to put a wand to his head and say Avada Kedavra!*" [Related](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/89759/31394). (I immediately wondered if that would be possible and was going to post a question about it, but of course it was a dupe.)

Comment: It would be fairly trivial, using _Priori Incantatem_, to show whether Lupin and Sirius’ wands were responsible for the spell(s) that would have caused Pettigrew’s death. The chances of success seem slim to none.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet They could have used Pettigrew's wand to kill him. Also very trivial. So we know that there are many ways that they could have done so!

Comment: It’s been quite a while since I read the books, but does Pettigrew have a wand at this point? Doesn’t he only get one later, after rejoining Voldemort? They could always claim that Pettigrew somehow managed to steal one of their wands and then killed himself with it, but that would be a hard sell.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet There you go! Another solution! :)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet knock him out with a stunner, cast a couple of shields and then use a cutting curse to end him, and the wand history will support their story rather than undermine it: a miss, a quick duel, and an unfortunately lethal cutter which was intended to disable his arm but ended up knicking his neck instead when he ducked unexpectedly.

Comment: @Morgen :D This made my day!

Answer (score 4):

**This will not be strictly illegal**

1. Peter Pettigrew is a death eater. Aurors and other members have killed death eaters in the series. It is mentioned that Barty Crouch authorized to kill many death eaters during the rise of Voldemort. Mrs.Weasly was not arrested for killing Bellatrix.
2. They don't have to use the unforgivable curses. Harry nearly killed Malfoy without using one. Sirius and Lupin are skilled wizards who can kill a person without using an unforgivable curse.

Besides, they could claim that it was an act of self-defence or they did it to defend Harry.

Comment: The laws on vigilantism must then be very lax in that universe. There is one thing to kill an enemy combatant in a war (like the death eaters during the rise of Voldemort) or killing in selfe-defense (like killing Bellatrix), versus summary execution during what was basically a "citizen's arrest".

Comment: @vsz No one outside will know how it happened. They could claim it was a combat or self-defence or in defence of Harry.

Comment: You claimed this will not be illegal. Being illegal or not doesn't mean being found out or not.

Comment: @vsz That depends on the Ministry. For example, Barty Crouch prefered to kill rather than capture but Mad-eye Moody always captured them alive if possible.

Answer (score 3):

Lupin and Sirius were after justice and revenge. Neither of them had anything to lose and even if they had, they couldn't see past their hatred for Peter's betrayal of their best friend, to consider their own lives and the outcome.

Lupin, was a werewolf and his kind were not treated well by the Wizarding community. Most of them couldn't get jobs, and lived underground. He finally had friends at Hogwarts, best friends that meant so much to him, as well as how much Lily meant to him, and lost everyone.

> "For the first time ever, I had friends, three great friends... I was terrified they would desert me the moment they found out what I was. But of course, they, like you, Hermione, worked out the truth... and they didn't desert me at all. Instead, they did something for me that would make my transformations not only bearable, but the best times of my life. They became Animagi.">

> "Your mother was there for me at a time when no one else was."

Lupin goes to great lengths to emphasize how important his friends were to him. This makes the betrayal of one of his friends (Peter), and the recent realization that this whole time, one of his friends never betrayed James (Sirius) so much more powerful. He would not abandon him or try to stop Sirius after finding out the truth. He also wants justice for the betrayal.

> ‘You should have realised,’ said Lupin quietly. ‘If Voldemort didn’t kill you, we would. Goodbye, Peter.’

Answer (score 3):

I think it was Sirius who wanted to kill him first.

> “They’ve — got — a — right — to — know — everything!” Lupin panted, still trying to restrain
> Black. “Ron’s kept him as a pet! There are parts of it even I don’t understand, and Harry — you
> owe Harry the truth, Sirius!” Black stopped struggling, though his hollowed eyes were still fixed on Scabbers, who was
> clamped tightly under Ron’s bitten, scratched, and bleeding hands.
> “All right, then,” Black said, without taking his eyes off the rat. “Tell them whatever you like.
> But make it quick, Remus. I want to commit the murder I was imprisoned for…”

And Remus was the type of person who followed his friends plans, he was like that since he was a student. He didn't stop James and Sirius when they attacked Snape although he was a prefect! And he came along with them while breaking the rules. Creating the marauders map, accompanying them when they became unregistered animagus, and we don't know what else.

> “I sometimes felt guilty about betraying Dumbledore’s trust, of course… he had admitted me to
> Hogwarts when no other headmaster would have done so, and he had no idea I was breaking the
> rules he had set down for my own and others’ safety. He never knew I had led three fellow
> students into becoming Animagi illegally. But I always managed to forget my guilty feelings
> every time we sat down to plan our next month’s adventure. And I haven’t changed…”

Perhaps he kinda felt like he always owed them, because no one else would have stayed his friend after learning his secret, let alone what they've done to make him feel better.
Also he may have felt guilt because he was the reason Pettigrew became close to Potters and knew their place.

> Remus, always the underdog’s friend, was kind to short and rather slow Peter Pettigrew, a fellow Gryffindor, whom James and Sirius might not have thought worthy of their attention without Remus’s persuasion. Soon, these four became inseparable.
>
> <sub>-- [Pottermore](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/remus-lupin)</sub>